# What happens if all data are added in same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I was wondering what happens if all data is added in a same table without using any other table or foreign key. What effects does it create on the performance if the data is very large.

This is sheer out of curiosity. Please do help on finding an answer on this.

Comment: You would get a table proportional to the size of your data and a very simple data model.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Would you please explain in brief, it would be so helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you could enter large data in single table as well but if you missed proper indexing and partitioning (if required) then the fetching of data will be very slow.

If you are using Binary column in the table then it would be worst.

As a best practice you should follow normalization and if that is not possible then you can use single table as well the only thing which you can prepare yourself for performance.

Use proper Index & partitioning will help in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

This question strongly depends on amount of data (what is 'huge'? 1 GB? 1 TB? 1 PB? ...) and the kind of data you have got (unstructured? images? movies? ...)

Obviously, your data would not be efficient except having only one table if this is something that one would want to call efficiency.

To see what would happen, you basically could test it yourself. You might use [AdventureWorks](https://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/) or [WorldwideImporters](https://github.com/microsoft/sql-server-samples) Database and then do something like that with a [Select Into](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql):

```
SELECT * INTO TABLETARGET FROM TABLESOURCE
```